# How to combine same kind of queries with different variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to combine my SQL queries and fetch their results all at once. I tried many JOIN methods but they all failed.

As performance matters for my site, I don't want to fetch them seperately and want to combine all of them. Which method is the best way for that? I need to learn a clear way of doing this, because I will implement all of my similar queries in same way.

```
$kacinci = mysql_query("SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM uye
WHERE bakiye>=(SELECT bakiye FROM uye WHERE ID='$profilid')");
$kacincix = mysql_fetch_array($kacinci);

$kackatinahafta = mysql_query("SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM uye
WHERE kackatinahafta>=(SELECT kackatinahafta FROM uye WHERE ID='$profilid')");
$kackatinahaftax = mysql_fetch_array($kackatinahafta);

$nekadarhafta = mysql_query("SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM uye
WHERE nekadarhafta>=(SELECT nekadarhafta FROM uye WHERE ID='$profilid')");
$nekadarhaftax = mysql_fetch_array($nekadarhafta);

$kackatinaay = mysql_query("SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM uye
WHERE kackatinaay>=(SELECT kackatinaay FROM uye WHERE ID='$profilid')");
$kackatinaayx = mysql_fetch_array($kackatinaay);

$nekadaray = mysql_query("SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM uye
WHERE nekadaray>=(SELECT nekadaray FROM uye WHERE ID='$profilid')");
$nekadarayx = mysql_fetch_array($nekadaray);
```

PS: I'm aware that mysql_query is deprecated and I need to upgrade to either PDO or mysqli_query. However, I need to use mysql_query for a special reason in this project.

Comment: have you tried `union` or you can also do a `subquery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation` with a `join` to return all records in a single row:

```
select
    sum(case when u.bakiye >= u2.bakiye then 1 
             else 0 end) bakiye_count,
    sum(case when u.kackatinahafta >= u2.kackatinahafta then 1 
             else 0 end) kackatinahafta_count,
    sum(case when u.nekadarhafta >= u2.nekadarhafta then 1 
             else 0 end) nekadarhafta_count,
    ...
from uye u
    join uye u2 on u2.id = '$profilid'
```

This assume `uye` has unique records on the id field.